# UIButton action for individual cell in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am having Two buttons in table view, my problem is: my button conditions should work in every separate cell. how can I do this, can anyone help me.

```
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"l"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button1 setTag:indexPath.row];


[cell addSubview:button1];




 button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 27, 36, 36);
[button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"v"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button3.tag = indexPath.row;
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[cell addSubview:button3];


- (void)radiobtn:(UIButton *)button
{
 if(btn3 == 0)
{

   if ([button isSelected]) {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"button1"];

        [button setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"button1"];
[button setSelected:YES];}}
else { }

}
- (void)radiobtn3:(UIButton *)button
{
 btn1 =[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"button1"]integerValue];




if(btn1 == 0)
{
    if ([button isSelected]) {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"button3"];
[button setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"button3"];
[button setSelected:YES]; }}
else {}

}
```

This above conditions are working good, but this conditions should works in individual cell.Please help me in coding, i am new to IOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your own custom cell and override a Class from UITableViewCell for your custom cell.

See [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702)